# HTML calculator , + doesnt works

Tags: html, forms, button, label, fieldset

I made a calculator, but `+` doesn't work, why?? -> if you want + something, you have to press button : sečíst   .... it doesn't + it, but it writes it in some bad way, take a look :  http://jsfiddle.net/p77roqhr/

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="cs-CZ"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="Prace"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="online_kalkulacka.css">
        <title>kalkulačka</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>        
        <h1>Kalkulačka</h1>
        <form name="kalkulacka">
            <fieldset>
                <div id="cislo1">
                    <label for="vypln_cislo1">zadej zde první číslo</label> <input id="1" type="number" name="prvni" min="0" max="10000">
                </div>
                <div id="cislo2">
                    <label for="vypln_cislo2">zadej zde druhé číslo</label> <input id="2" type="number" name="druhe" min="0" max="10000">
                </div>
                    <button id="b1" onclick="document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('1').value + document.getElementById('2').value; return false;">sečíst</button>
                    <button id="b2" onclick="document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('1').value - document.getElementById('2').value; return false;">odečíst</button>
                    <button id="b3" onclick="document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('1').value / document.getElementById('2').value; return false;">vydělit</button>
                    <button id="b4" onclick="document.getElementById('3').innerText = document.getElementById('1').value * document.getElementById('2').value; return false;">vynásobit</button>
                <div id="vysledek">
                    výsledek je : 
                    <br>
                    <div id="vysledek2">
                        <span id="3"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert each to a number first so it will add them like a number instead of doing string concatenation.  Look for `parseInt()`.

Change your code to

```
<button id="b1" onclick="document.getElementById('3').innerText = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value, 10) + parseInt(document.getElementById('2').value, 10); return false;">sečíst</button>
```

Comment: That's because * / and - requires that the operands get converted to numbers automatically.  In the case of +, it thinks that you want to combine/append the strings together.  See my edit for the code change.

Comment: female here... we can code too! :-)  Please accept my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: sorry, sis:D , ill need to wait 5 minutes to do that, and i will wait:P